# Eclipse method printing?

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

I am working in Eclipse with a program that someone else wrote, There is a certain section where I cannot figure out the procedure of method calls. It seems like methods that modify a class are being called from nowhere at all. 
 
Is there a way to see the order that methods are called in eclipse? Like as a debugging feature. Or would I manually have to go add println's to thousands of methods?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to set a breakpoint in the method being called "from nowhere", and then inspect the call stack to see from where the invocation came.

The screenshot below shows the call stack in the top-left corner of the IDE.

[image]

Comment: i might be wrong, but i don't think the OP is asking how to use the debugger

Comment: I didnt even know the call stack could be inspected, thats exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click the method name, and select Open Call Hierarchy. That will givwe a list of places where the method is called from, and where *they* are called from etc.

Alternatively you can `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

That returns an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)s that represent the current stack trace of a program. You can iterate and print as if it were an exception stack trace, to see where the method was actually called from.